# Find gaps between datetime from different subsequence rows

Tags: mysql, datetime

How to find gaps between datetime from different rows? Take below as an sample.

```
Id  DateTime             Door 
1   2016-01-01 08:00:00  In   
2   2016-01-01 09:00:00  Out  
3   2016-01-01 09:15:00  In   
4   2016-01-01 09:30:00  In   
5   2016-01-01 10:00:00  Out  
6   2016-01-01 11:00:00  In   
7   2016-01-01 12:00:00  In   
8   2016-01-01 13:00:00  In   
9   2016-01-01 13:30:00  Out  
10  2016-01-01 14:00:00  Out  
11  2016-01-01 15:00:00  In
```

After this code,

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as id,
   max(case when door = 'in' then datetime end) as clockin,
   max(case when door = 'out' then datetime end) as clockout
from (select t.*,
         @grp := if(@d = door, @grp,
                    if(@d := door, @grp + 1, @grp + 1)
                   ) as grp
  from t cross join
       (select @d := '', @grp := 0) param
  order by id
 ) t cross join
 (select @rn := 0) param
group by floor((grp - 1) / 2)
```

Will output his:

```
Id  Clock In             Clock Out             
1   2016-01-01 08:00:00  2016-01-01 09:00:00   
2   2016-01-01 09:30:00  2016-01-01 10:00:00   
3   2016-01-01 13:00:00  2016-01-01 14:00:00
```

Thanks to Gordon for the code. But now I would like to find the time gaps between clock out and clock in from the next rows as below:

```
Id  Clock In             Clock Out             Gaps
1   2016-01-01 08:00:00  2016-01-01 09:00:00   00:00:00
2   2016-01-01 09:30:00  2016-01-01 10:00:00   00:30:00  
3   2016-01-01 13:00:00  2016-01-01 14:00:00   03:00:00
```

I have tried this so far but it gave me gaps between clock out and clock in from  same rows:

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as id,
   max(case when door = 'in' then datetime end) as clockin,
   max(case when door = 'out' then datetime end) as clockout,
   timediff(max(case when door = 'out' then datetime end),max(case when door   = 'in' then datetime end)) as gaps
 from (select t.*,
         @grp := if(@d = door, @grp,
                    if(@d := door, @grp + 1, @grp + 1)
                   ) as grp
  from t cross join
       (select @d := '', @grp := 0) param
  order by id
 ) t cross join
 (select @rn := 0) param
  group by floor((grp - 1) / 2)
```

Please help me guys. Appreciate your effort and help.

Comment: A quite similar question has been asked today?

Comment: Not similar Dylan, it is to find the time gaps between rows from the result we get just now. I can only manage to find the gaps between datetimes on the same rows, but not from different rows.

Comment: `if(@d := door, @grp + 1, @grp + 1)` Erm, really??

Comment: That line is to find pairs of last clock in and last clock out. Nothing's wrong there. I just want to ask how to find gaps between the last clock out and next clock in.

Comment: This line doesn't do anything (other than set @d:= door)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(Id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,DateTime DATETIME NOT NULL
,Door VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1   ,'2016-01-01 08:00:00',  'In'),
(2   ,'2016-01-01 09:00:00',  'Out'),
(3   ,'2016-01-01 09:15:00',  'In'),
(4   ,'2016-01-01 09:30:00',  'In'),
(5   ,'2016-01-01 10:00:00',  'Out'),
(6   ,'2016-01-01 11:00:00',  'In'),
(7   ,'2016-01-01 12:00:00',  'In'),
(8   ,'2016-01-01 13:00:00',  'In'),
(9   ,'2016-01-01 13:30:00',  'Out'),
(10  ,'2016-01-01 14:00:00',  'Out'),
(11  ,'2016-01-01 15:00:00',  'In');

SELECT n.id
     , n.datetime
     , n.door
     , n.diff
  FROM
     (
    SELECT x.*
     , TIMEDIFF(datetime,@prev) diff
     , @prev := datetime
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT DISTINCT MAX(b.id) id FROM my_table a JOIN my_table b ON b.door <> a.door AND b.id <= a.id GROUP BY a.id) y 
    ON y.id = x.id
  JOIN (SELECT @prev:=null) vars
 ORDER 
    BY id
    ) n
   WHERE door = 'in';

+----+---------------------+------+----------+
| id | datetime            | door | diff     |
+----+---------------------+------+----------+
|  1 | 2016-01-01 08:00:00 | In   | NULL     |
|  4 | 2016-01-01 09:30:00 | In   | 00:30:00 |
|  8 | 2016-01-01 13:00:00 | In   | 03:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Unknown column 'b.id' in 'field list'

Comment: my bad. I thought you edited the code I provided. It's actually totally a new query and it's work. Thanks for the idea. :)